# HP EliteBook 8530p wifi problem (hard blocked) in Qubes OS

Tags: linux, wifi, virtual-machine, qubes

I just installed Qubes OS on an old HP EliteBook 8530p and cannot connect to the internet with wireless.

This laptop has a physical wireless switch that must be toggled 'on' for the wireless to work. The switch is now set to 'off' (indicated with a red light) and cannot be toggled 'on'.

Rfkill tells me it the wireless is hard blocked.

I have tried:

- `rfkill unblock all`
- Reset bios to default

I no longer have Windows installed on the laptop. The WiFi-button previously worked fine in Ubuntu and Kali. Two other buttons also don't work: a projector-button and an information-button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the WiFi button already worked in Ubuntu and Kali then it could be that support for the button was included in the kernel (assuming the Ubuntu/Kali kernel was an updated version than that currently on Qubes). In this case an update to Qubes 3.1 could do the trick.

It could also be that a certain Debian package(s) on Ubuntu/Kali supported the button. If you could find out which package(s) (if any) were responsible, you could install them on your Debian template in Qubes and then base your NetVM on this template.